# Covert a column to a factor and then use group_by and summarise to calculate min, mean, and maximum salaries for each grade

Tags: r

I have used the following code to convert the column 'Grade' to a factor

````
```{r}
salaries <- 
  salaries %>% 
  mutate_at(c("Grade"), factor)
```
````

I have used the following code which I have used previously that ran to calculate the min mean and max salaries but an error message comes up

```
   grade_stats <- 
     salaries %>% 
     group_by(Grade)%>%
     summarise(min_salary = min(salaries$Salary), mean_salary = mean(salaries$Salary), max_salary=max(salaries$Salary))
   grade_stats
```

error message - Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `min_salary = min(salaries$Salary)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Grade = 3B.
Caused by error in `Summary.factor()`:
! ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
Backtrace:

1. salaries %>% group_by(Grade) %>% ...
2. base::Summary.factor(`<fct>`, na.rm = FALSE)
3. base::stop(gettextf("%s not meaningful for factors", sQuote(.Generic)))

Comment: Could you share `dput(head(salaries))` please ?

Comment: I have got it too work now, not sure what happened but just re ran the code a few times and it worked

Comment: BTW, you dont need to use `$` in the summarise function